# prove there is no rational r satisfying $2^r=3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I first assumed that there exists a rational $r=\frac{a}{b}$ such that $2^r=3$.

..and I can't make a progress after this.

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 23):

Suppose $r=\frac{a}{b}$ with coprime positive integers $a,b$.

Then, we get $$2^{\frac{a}{b}}=3$$

Take the $b-th$ power on both sides

$$2^a=3^b$$

This is clearly a contradiction because the left side is even and the right side
is odd.

Comment: We do not even need to assume that $a,b$ are coprime!

Comment: Quick typing! You got there first!

Comment: Hello, I have a confusion, before finding $2^a$ and $3^b$, why couldn't we be sure the left side is even? Is it because we don't know if $2^r$ would be even or odd when r is a fraction?

Comment: @alu Suppose r = 1/2. Notice that $2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not an integer, and so the notion of parity (even/odd) isn't necessarily defined for all rationals r. This is why you need integers a and b to get to this contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

More generally,
suppose that
$a^n = b^m$
where all variables
are positive integers
and there is a prime $p$
such that
$p$ divides $a$
and
$p$ dies not divide $b$.

Then
$p$ divides $a^n$
and $p$ does not divide $b^m$,
which is a contradiction.

Therefore,
if $a^n = b^m$,
then every prime that divides $a$
must divide $b$
and vice versa.

More general results can be stated
(by looking at the complete 
prime factorizations),
but this is a reasonable generalization
of your problem.