# Prove there is no rational number r such that $2^r = 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Prove there is no rational number r such that $2^r = 3$.
I am wondering if my proof is correct.

$\mathbf{Proof:}$ We will provide a proof by contradiction. Assume there is a rational number r such that $2^r = 3$. This means by definition $r=\frac{p}{q}$$\;$ $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ with p and q having no common factors. We write $2^{\frac{p}{q}}=3$. Raise both sides to the $q^{th}$ power to get $2^p=3^q$. We have two cases to take care of, $\;r=0$ and $r\not = 0$. The first case being $\;r=0\;$, if $\;r = 0$ then p has to be zero because if q was zero then we wouldn't be able to complete the operation. If $\;r = 0$ then we have that $1=3\;$ which is a contradiction. For $r \not= 0$ we have two different cases, $r>0$ and $r<0$. First we will take care of the $r>0$ case. If $r>0$ then $p,q>0$ and we have $2^p=3^q$ which says an even number is equal to an odd number which is a contradiction. Finally, we take care of the $r<0$ case. If $r<0$ then $r=-\frac{p}{q}\; p,q\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ which implies $2^{-\frac{p}{q}}=3$$\;\Rightarrow $$\; \frac{1}{2^p}=3^q$$\;\Rightarrow\;$$1=2^p3^q $ which is a contradiction because $\:6\leq2^p3^q\:$ and $6\not\leq 1$.

Thanks y'all for the help.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Basically, you can argue based on uniqueness of prime factorisation (slightly more general) or the even-odd argument you're using. But it's much simpler than what you wrote. $2^p$ is always even and $3^q$ is always odd. Equality implies contradiction. I can't follow what you're doing, but it doesn't have to be that complicated.

Comment: I guess what I was hung up on was that I didn't know if $3^q$ was always even or always odd so I wanted to make an argument for both cases. @Deepak

Comment: First post on the site is a great one, +1 and the proof is right. Also note that this shows that $\log_2 3$ is irrational.

Comment: You can use even/odd, but more generally, for example $6^r=10,$ you can use unique factorization.

Comment: $3^q = 1 \implies q = 0$ and $\frac {p}{q}$ is not defined.

Comment: "The first case $p=0$ which gives $3^q=1$ meaning $3^q$ is odd"   What's wrong with that? $2^0 =1$ is odd too. so there's nothing wrong with $3^q = 1$ being odd.  More to the point is if $p = 0$ then $r=\frac pq = 0$ and $2^r = 2^0 =1$ and $1$ is not equal to $3$.  (Also as Doug M points out $3^q= 1$ means $q=0$ and $r = \frac pq = \frac 00$ is undefined.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider if $r < 0$.  And you need to redo if $r = 0$ correctly.

If $r > 0$ then there are $p, q \in \mathbb Z^+$ where $r =\frac pq$ and, although we can claim $p, q$ have no common factors that is not relevant or necessary.  Your argument was *PERFECT*.  $2^{\frac pq} =3 \implies 2^p = 3^q$ but LHS is even and RHS is odd.  *Beautiful*!

If $r = 0$ you kind of botch it.  You say  $2^0 = 3^q$  so $3^q = 1$ is odd which.... is not a contradiction.  More to the point:  If $r = 0$ then $2^r = 2^0=1$ which.... is not equal to $3$  That's all there is to it.

And to consider $r < 0$, if $r < 0$ then there are $p,q \in \mathbb Z^+$ so that $r =-\frac pq$ so $2^{-\frac pq} = \frac 1{2^{\frac pq}} = 3$ so raise both sides to the $q$ power and get $\frac 1{2^p} = 3^q$ and LHS is less than $1$ while RHS is more than $1$.

Comment: I think I finally have it completed. Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: Hello, is this okay to just use this argument in the link https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1427223/455531 instead of considering the cases when $r \gt 0, r = 0$ or $r \lt 0$?

Answer (score 3):

There are several logical mistakes in your argument:

($1$) $2^p=3^q$ does not imply $3^q$ is a multiple of $2$. You need to consider the case $p=0$ and $p \neq0$ separately.

($2$) "In the case that $2^p$ is odd we have an even number being equal to an odd number which is also a contradiction"

This statement is not correct. When $p=0$, we have an odd number equals an odd number. The fallacy comes from the assumption in ($1$)

Edit: as comment by Graham Kemp points out, you also need to prove the case where $p<0$ and $q>0$, which is trivial but need to be stated.

Comment: I made an edit. Does this button up the proof?

Comment: There is also the possibility that $r$ may be a *negative rational number*.  So if $r=p/q$ where $p\in\Bbb Z, q\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $2^p$ may be an even integer, $1$, or an non-integer.

Comment: @yastown Your proof looks better now and the $p\neq 0$ case looks good to me. But you still haven't proved the $p=0$ case, which would involve something like "$q$ is the denominator and cannot be zero".

Comment: @Graham Kemp You are correct. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

A direct sort of answer $2^r=3 \implies r=\log_2 3 \notin Q$

Comment: That's basically what we're trying to prove.